# How to read and parse a plist

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, plist

I like to read and parse plist files, but It wont work.

This is my code: `NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.plistPath];`
dict always is (null)

I tryed to get the content as string, here is my code:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.plistPath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

self.plistPath is /tmp/com.apple.audio.hogmode.plist
```

And this is the content of the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the file contents? Are you sure that it is a property list representing a dictionary?

Comment: Please show self.plistPath value or a code you are using to create it.

Comment: I have tested your code with exactly your plist contents, and the result was an empty dictionary, as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.plistPath] mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];
```